# Applescript to extract the Digital Object Identifier (DOI) from a PDF file

Tags: regex, pdf, applescript

I looked for an applescript to extract the DOI from a PDF file, but could not find it. There is enough information available on the actual format of the DOI (i.e. the regular expression), but *how could I use this to get the identifier from the PDF file*?

(It would be no problem if some external program were used, such as Hazel.)

Comment: can you put a sample data and the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with pdfgrep? It works really well in commmandline

```
pdfgrep -n --max-count 1 --include "*.pdf" "DOI"
```

i have no idea to build an apple script though, but i would be interested in one also. so that if i drop a pdf into that folder it just automatically extracts the DOI and renames the file with the DOI in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with using an app, I'd recommend Skim. Good AppleScript support. I'd probably structure it like this (especially if the document might be large):

```
set DOIFound to false
tell application "Skim"
    set pp to pages of document 1
    repeat with p in pp
        set t to text of p
        --look for DOI and set DOIFound to true
        if DOIFound then exit repeat--if it's not found then use url?
    end repeat
end tell
```

I'm assuming a DOI would always exist on one page (not spread out to between two). Looks like they are invariably (?) on the first page of an article, which would make this quick of course, even with a large doc.

**[edit]**

Another way would be to get the Xpdf OSX binaries from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html and use pdftotext in the command line (just tested this; it works well) and parse the text using AppleScript. If you want to stay in AppleScript, you can do something like:

```
do shell script "path/to/pdftotext 'path/to/pdf/file.pdf'"
```

which would output a file in the same directory with a txt file extension -- you parse that for DOI.